# Change the columns which include max and min values python

Tags: python

I can't understand why it doesn't change the whole column but only one value of each of the column

finding the index of max value >>

```
  def findmax(row,col,newmatrix):
    index=0
    max=newmatrix[0][0]
    for i in range(0,row):
        for j in range(col):
            if newmatrix[i][j] > max :
                max = newmatrix[i][j]
                index = j
    return index
```

finding index of min value >>

```
def findmin(row,col,newmatrix):
    index=0
    min=newmatrix[0][0]
    for i in range(0,row):
        for j in range(col):
            if newmatrix[i][j] < min :
                min = newmatrix[i][j]
                index = j
    return index
```

changing the columns of highest and lowest value

```
def change(row,col,newmatrix):
    for i in range (0,row):
        temp=newmatrix[i][findmax(row, col, newmatrix)]
        newmatrix[i][findmax(row, col, newmatrix)] = newmatrix[i][findmin(row, col, newmatrix)]
        newmatrix[i][findmin(row, col, newmatrix)] = temp
        for j in range(0,col):
             print('%.2f'%newmatrix[i][j], end = " ")
        print()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code doesn't work for you, because you are repeating your function for each row, simultaneously when you change the whole matrix (so it will be returning different values for each row).

In order to fix your code just do before the `for` loop `x=findmax(row, col, newmatrix)` and then refer to `x` inside the loop instead of calling the function.

In general though I would rewrite your code to numpy, so you can operate on columns. I think something like that would do the trick for you:

```py
import numpy as np
x=np.array([[1,4,5], [7,4,2], [4,3,-2]])

x_max=np.unravel_index(x.argmax(axis=None), x.shape)

x_min=np.unravel_index(x.argmin(axis=None), x.shape)

temp=x[:,x_max[1]].copy()

x[:,x_max[1]]=x[:,x_min[1]]
x[:,x_min[1]]=temp

print(X)
```

And output:

```py
[[ 5  4  1]
 [ 2  4  7]
 [-2  3  4]]

[Program finished]
```

Comment: i can't import/install numpy on my PC, i also have to do this in C++, so have to figure out something else :D

Comment: In such case just do before the ```for``` loop ```x=findmax(row, col, newmatrix)``` and then refer to ```x``` inside the loop instead of calling the function.

Comment: No worries, please mark the question as an answer to close it off.